# When copying a file from USB to USB, does Windows 7 cache a copy of the file?

Tags: windows-7, usb

I plugged 2 USB drives into a Windows 7 laptop and copied a file straight from one drive to the other. Would the laptop have a copy of that file on it somewhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it wouldn't. Parts of the file may be cached in memory, but extracting those parts and sorting out which parts are missing will be either incredibly difficult or impossible.

Comment: I think it should go without saying but it's perhaps worth noting to @BattlFrog that even if parts of those files are in memory they will not stay there permanently. Things like rebooting the computer or having high utilization of memory will cause those pieces to go entirely away relatively quickly.

Comment: @Abraxas Yep, good addendum.